# how can I define a default constructor while I have other constructors?

Tags: java

I have a class in Java. This class has a constructor like below:

```
public Person(String first, String last) {
    firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(first);
    lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(last);
    city = new SimpleStringProperty("Tehran");
    street = new SimpleStringProperty("Vali Asr");
    postalCode = new SimpleStringProperty("23456");
    birthday = new SimpleStringProperty("12345");
}
```

Now I want to declare a constructor like below:

```
public Person() {
    Person(null, null);
}
```

But it gives me an error.
What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: use `this(null, null)` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling `Person(null, null)` doesn't work because **a constructor is not a method** so it cannot be called like a method as you are trying to do.
What you need to do is rather to call `this(null, null)` to invoke the other constructor as next:

```
public Person() {
    this(null, null); // this(...) like super(...) is only allowed if it is 
                      // the first instruction of your constructor's body
}

public Person(String first, String last) {
    ...
}
```

More details about the keyword `this` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: Note that calls to `this(...)` or `super(...)` must always be the first instruction within a constructor. This also means that you can call either `this(...)` or `super(...)`, but not both.

Comment: public Person(String first, String last) {
        //Set of stmts

    }

    public Person() {
        this(null, null);
    }